# Unable to get browser for IE11 on remote webdriver after login

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

The script used:

```
DesiredCapabilities iecap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
iecap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
iecap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
iecap.setCapability("nativeEvents", true); 
iecap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", false);
iecap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
iecap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
iecap.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", false);
iecap.setCapability("ensureCleanSession", true);
iecap.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);

IEdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteServer), iecap);
```

IE opening in remote machine and able to enter data, click on elements.. everything is fine but when I'm logged in then I am facing this issue

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

After clicking on login button, I am able to see window available with logged in.but fails.

If I use normal driver in local, every thing is fine. No issue after login.

Before posting question, searched, tried but didn't get solution. note that I cant chane registry as server machine is not in my control but in my local its working without changing registry keys as suggested in wiki.

Comment: Are you using updated jars and IEdriver?

Comment: @ShubhamJain yes. latest jar and IEDriver, also seen same issue in latest selenium2 means 2.53.1.

Comment: Selenium and IEDriverServer version please? Are you running on Hub & Node on localhost?